# Replacing words in a string- but with two different words: Python3

Tags: python, string, loops, python-3.x

Trying to get it so that it takes input the same number of times the certain word appears in the original string and replaces it with each word that was the input.

```
def replace_parts_of_speech (replaced, part_of_speech):
    '''Finds and replaces parts of speech with words '''
    new_line=''

    for i in range (replaced.count(part_of_speech)):
        new=input('Enter '+ part_of_speech +':') 
        new_line = replaced.replace(part_of_speech,new,1)


    return new_line
```

Comment: This for Mad Libs, yes?  Would you please post example input and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: replace_parts_of_speech ('noun in noun verb', 'noun')
Enter noun= 1
Enter noun= 2

Expected: '1 in 2 verb'
Got:  '2 in noun verb'

Comment: add expected output to your question not to comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, each time through the loop, you create a whole new `new_line`, ignoring the previous `new_line` and just going back to the original `replaced`. So, only the last replacement will be visible when the loop is done.

```
for i in range (replaced.count(part_of_speech)):
    new=input('Enter '+ part_of_speech +':') 
    new_line = replaced.replace(part_of_speech,new,1)
```

So, the second replacement ignores the first one.

What you want to do is this:

```
new_line = replaced
for i in range (replaced.count(part_of_speech)):
    new=input('Enter '+ part_of_speech +':') 
    new_line = new_line.replace(part_of_speech,new,1)
```

---

A simplified example of the same problem might be easier to understand:

```
start = 0
current = 0
for i in range(5):
    current = start + i
print(current)
```

This will just print `4`. But now:

```
start = 0
current = start
for i in range(5):
    current = current + i
print(current)
```

This will print `10`.

Comment: Exactly- thanks for clearing that up. My brain was just derping out. :)